# Angular - Redirect user to login page when server goes down

Tags: angular

I have working login and refresh token session. But I have issue to redirect user to login page when the server goes down for some reason.
The issue I have is it redirects to main page and then after few ms it goes to the login page. The behaviour I am expecting is it should directly show the login page. Why this behaviour??

```
 this.sockjsService.jobStatusClose$.subscribe(value => {
        console.log("value  -----------", value+"  this.data.job_status   ",this.data.job_status);
        if(value === 3 && this.data.job_status==='NEW')
        {
            alert("Server is down!!");             
            this.dialogRef.close();
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return;
        }       
    });
```

Comment: You say you are redirected to your main page, but the code you posted does not have the code which redirects you to main page. I guess the cause is outside of your post.

Comment: in the code I tell it to redirect me to the login page BUT the app takes me to the main page